# Error handling in java

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

Am running `.exe` file from java code using ProcessBulider, the code I have written is given below. The `.exe` file takes `Input.txt`(placed in same directory) as input and provide 3 output file in same directory.

```
public void ExeternalFileProcessing() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String executableFileName = "I:/Rod/test.exe;

    ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject=new ProcessBuilder(executableFileName,"Input.txt");

    File absoluteDirectory = new File("I:/Rod");

    processBuilderObject.directory(absoluteDirectory);

    Process process = processBuilderObject.start();

    process.waitFor();
}
```

this process is working fine by call `ExeternalFileProcessing()`. Now am doing validation process, If there is any crash/.exe file doesn't run, I should get the error message how can I get error message?

**Note:** It would be better that error message be simple like `run successful/doesn't run successful` or simply `true/false`, so that I can put this in `If` condition to continue the remaining process.

Answer (score 1):

You can add exception handlers to get the error message.

```
public void externalFileProcessing() {

    String executableFileName = "I:/Rod/test.exe";

    ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject = new ProcessBuilder(
            executableFileName, "Input.txt");

    File absoluteDirectory = new File("I:/Rod");

    processBuilderObject.directory(absoluteDirectory);


    try {
        Process process = processBuilderObject.start();
        process.waitFor();
        // this code will be executed if the process works
                    System.out.println("works");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // this code will be executed if a IOException happens "e.getMessage()" will have an error
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // this code will be executed if the thread is interrupted
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it would be better to handle it in the calling function by put a try catch handler in the calling function and handling it there.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a third party .exe or do you have access to its sources? If so, you could work with basic System outputs (for example couts to the console).
Those outputs can be redirected to your java app using something like this:

```
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {        
    if(line.equals("something")) {
        // do something
    }
}
br.close();
```

This is how i do things like that and it works very well in general. But i must admit, that i can not say/garuantee, that this is THE way to do it. A more advanced approach might be the use of [StreamGobbler](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) (see Listing 4.5) to handle the outputs of the .exe.
Let me know if it helped you or not.